# Error importing tensorflow running python in the home directory

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

Team,
I have a problem importing tensorflow if I run python from the home directory terminal. Please see below:

```
rkenaya@rkenaya:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import node_def_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_node__def__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/node_def_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import resource_handle_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_resource__handle__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
    serialized_pb=_b('\n/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.proto\x12\ntensorflow\"r\n\x13ResourceHandleProto\x12\x0e\n\x06\x64\x65vice\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x11\n\tcontainer\x18\x02 \x01(\t\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x12\x11\n\thash_code\x18\x04 \x01(\x04\x12\x17\n\x0fmaybe_type_name\x18\x05 \x01(\tB/\n\x18org.tensorflow.frameworkB\x0eResourceHandleP\x01\xf8\x01\x01\x62\x06proto3')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'
>>>
```

However I do not get any error if I run python from python native directory. Please see below:

```
rkenaya@rkenaya:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
>>>
```

Note: I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Any help would be highly appreciated folks.

Riyadh

Comment: Do you have a 'tensorflow' directoy in your home directory?

Comment: No I don't have.

Comment: might be a protobuf issue - what's the output of: `import google.protobuf;
print(google.protobuf.__version__)`? see [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/57) and [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11)

Comment: Did not give any output. I kept waiting on the terminal forever

Comment: I think I have solved the problem. But the way the problem is solved is not satisfying me. 

sudo python instead of python is the solution.